# Can't get rid of CDATA in XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, transformation, cdata

I have a simple-lookong problem. I have a generated XML, where a specific important HTML part is in CDATA such as:

`<text><![CDATA[<p>some text</p>]]></text>`

I need to convert this into another xml(MS word format). I would be great if I could  handle this part like this(without CDATA) in XSLT:

`<text><p>some text</p></text>`

Is there a way to do it in XSLT? I tried almost everything with disable-output-escaping="yes"..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, Not until XSLT 3.0**, which is still a WD.

You will need to use an extension function like **[`saxon:parse()`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/parse.xml)** or if you are using another XSLT processor, write this extension function yourself.